# Запуск метода в новом потоке Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть контейнер (ListView) и я читаю в него файл, ну соответственно, когда файл большой программа виснет. Что этого не случалось, я пытался сделать многопоточность, но что-то не так понял видимо и не могу вызвать саму функцию в отдельном потоке.
Вот что получилось у меня.

```
ObservableList<String> lines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(lines);
LoaderDoc loaderDoc = new LoaderDoc();
loaderDoc.start();
loaderDoc.loadDoc (selectedItem, listView); //отправляю сюда listView, чтоб он наполнился данными из файла.
Tab tab = new Tab(selectedItem.getValue().getName());
```

В классе **LoaderDoc**

```
public class LoaderDoc extends Thread {


    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread LoaderDoc run!");
    }

    public void loadDoc(TreeItem<File> selectedItem, ListView<String> listView) {
        /*ObservableList<String> lines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       // ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(lines);*/
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        listView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
        listView.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<String> t) {
                listView.getItems().set(t.getIndex(), t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        listView.setEditable(true); // change
        listView.getItems().clear();
        int numRom = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedItem.getValue().getAbsolutePath()));
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                numRom++;
                listView.getItems().add(numRom + ": " + s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Так же возникли следующие вопросы по многопоточке.
Многопоточен только метод run?
У меня есть класс с несколькими статическими (и не только статическими) методами, которые мне нужно вызывать, возможно ли как-нибудь вызывать каждый в отдельном потоке, чтоб не грузить основной?

Буду рад вашим пояснениям.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что единственный способ решения данной проблемы, каждый метод сунуть в отдельный класс, через конструктор записывать параметры и вызывать метод через run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потоки запускаются в методе `run()` интерфейса `Runnable`

```
ObservableList<String> lines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(lines);
Thread thread = new Thread(new LoaderDoc(selectedItem, listView));
thread.start(); //отправляю сюда listView, чтоб он наполнился данными из файла.
Tab tab = new Tab(selectedItem.getValue().getName());
```

Сам класс потока

```
public class LoaderDoc implements Runnable {
        private TreeItem<File> selectedItem;
        private ListView<String> listView;

        public LoaderDoc(TreeItem<File> selectedItem, ListView<String> listView) {
            this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
            this.listView = listView;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread LoaderDoc run!");
            loadDoc(selectedItem, listView);
        }

        private void loadDoc(TreeItem<File> selectedItem, ListView<String> listView) {
        /*ObservableList<String> lines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       // ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(lines);*/
            listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
            listView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
            listView.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<String> t) {
                    listView.getItems().set(t.getIndex(), t.getNewValue());
                }
            });
            listView.setEditable(true); // change
            listView.getItems().clear();
            int numRom = 0;
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedItem.getValue().getAbsolutePath()));
                String s;
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    numRom++;
                    listView.getItems().add(numRom + ": " + s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

В этом классе мы создали конструктор, чтобы передать в него необходимые объекты/параметры, которые присваиваем приватным полям класса, а их (приватные поля) в свою очередь уже передаем в метод `loadDoc()`, который запустим в методе `run()`.

То, что мы сейчас сделали, это не многопоточность, это параллельный поток. Многопоточность - это немного другое, изучите этот вопрос.

Вызывать методы вы можете в сколько угодно потоках, если для этого хватит ресурсов устройства.

Если методы выполняют работу для одного результата и вас устроит, что они будут выполнены линейно, то их можно запустить в одном методе `run` в рамках одного класса.

Если это принципиально разные методы, и их логика не имеет ничего общего, то для исключения взаимного влияния (они будут выполняться линейно в одном потоке, например) можно запускать их в разных потоках.

Comment: Не работает ```Error:(155, 96) java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.Thread```
Cкриншот результата
https://sun9-37.userapi.com/c855016/v855016116/1e4d5c/GvDrjzeyfH0.jpg

Comment: Проблема в вашем `listView` @WBLord

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с новой проблемой. На данный вопрос я дал ответ, его можно пометить соответственно.

Comment: Ваш способ не работает, и вызывает ошибку, поэтому я и переспросил

Comment: @WBLord мой способ работает, ищите проблему в listview

Comment: @WBLord исправил ответ, не заметил ошибку)

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае, мне помогло

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            //тут код
            }
        }).start();
```

и вот этот вариант

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
new LoaderDoc(selectedItem, listView).run();
});
```